# How do i texture an object composed of multiple sub-objects?

Tags: texturing, uv, game-engine

I created this little thing the other day: 
[image]

and this is its hierarchy in Blender:

[image]

The current render is using multiple materials (main white plastic, yellowish part, black parts, and shiny disc) i would like for everything (except the disc) to share the same material and texture, am aiming to use a texture that is basically a bunch of squares that makes a color palette, and UV map the model so each object is using the correct color, (except for the disk that would probably need its own material cause its too shiny, but let's ignore that for now)

Knowing that my object will be used in a game (made with Unity), what are my options to achieve that.

PS:
for some reason i find myself afraid of merging objects, i just like the organization of having them separated, this is also kinda important when making games, so i mainly want to know if its possible for a bunch of objects to share the same UV map/texture

thanks!

Comment: Why not merge a copy of the objects, leave originals intact? Unwrap your meshes before merging then texture the joined copy

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos i thought about that, but like i said, am "afraid" of merging objects, i like the flexibility of having each object on its own, and for a game, say i want to "destroy" that music box and have each part fly somewhere, it would be easier to do it with an organization like this isn't ?

PS: am totally new to this so i might be 100% wrong so if you have any advice please share it :) thanks!

Comment: It's relatively easy to preserve your existing hierarchy by using vertex groups.  Create a different vertex group for each individual object, assign all verts to that object, and now each object is individually selectable even after joining.  (And if you want to blow it up, all you have to do is add appropriately named bones and use an armature.)

Comment: @Nathan oh!! i used Vertex groups a coupe of times before but exclusively for animation purposes, i'll give this a try! thanks

Comment: @Nathan just a question (am not home so i can't try this now) but suppose you create an object, say a simple cube, you enter edit mode, and create another cube which is gonna be a part of the original object, now you select the newly created cube and add it to a vertex group, if you start editing that 2nd cube, extruding and adding tons of new vertices, will the the vertex group be updated too ?

Comment: Most operations will try to be smart about it, interpolating where appropriate, but some things, like a vertex slide IIRC, aren't as smart.  Check the operators panel.  But for solidly painted groups like we're talking about here, anything short of creating new verts out of thin air (shift a, ctrl LMB) would be fine.

Comment: @Nathan your vertex group suggestion saved my day man :) https://imgur.com/a/uKQMWr7